# <unknown> Error occured in detectAndCompute()

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When I ran my code under debugger, it showed an `<unknown>` error in:

```
detector->detectAndCompute( matInput, noArray(), keypoints2, descriptors2 );
```

like this [image: this]

```
`matInput` is from `inputFrame.rgba()`
```

Java code in :

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
```

and this is not null.

This is a part of 
**native-lib.cpp**:

```
std::vector<Mat> trainImages;

std::vector< std::vector<DMatch> > knn_matches;
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1;
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints2;

Mat matImg;

static void createKeypointsAndDescriptors(const Mat& matInput) {

    int minHessian = 400;
    cv::Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( minHessian ); 
    std::vector<KeyPoint> temp_keypoints;
    std::vector<std::vector<KeyPoint>> temp_keypoints1;
    Mat temp_descriptors;
    std::vector<Mat> temp_descriptors1;
    Mat descriptors2;
    std::vector< std::vector<DMatch> > temp_knn_matches;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        detector->detectAndCompute( trainImages[i], noArray(), temp_keypoints, temp_descriptors );
        temp_keypoints1.push_back(temp_keypoints);
        temp_descriptors1.push_back(temp_descriptors);
    }

    detector->detectAndCompute( matInput, noArray(), keypoints2, descriptors2 );        

    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create(DescriptorMatcher::FLANNBASED);
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        if(temp_keypoints[i].size >= 2 && keypoints2.size() >= 2)
            matcher->knnMatch( temp_descriptors1[i], descriptors2, temp_knn_matches, 2 );

        if(max < temp_knn_matches.size()) {
            max = temp_knn_matches.size();
            keypoints1 = temp_keypoints1[i];
            matImg = trainImages[i];
            knn_matches = temp_knn_matches;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's my example input image [image: A image]

This is a code related image. I send images from the `asset` directory to `JNI` by using `java` code.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_surfwithflann2_MainActivity_sendImages(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                       jlongArray tempAddrObj_) {

    if(trainImages.size() == 0) {
        int length = env->GetArrayLength(tempAddrObj_);
        jlong *tempAddrObj = env->GetLongArrayElements(tempAddrObj_, NULL);

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            cv::Mat &tempImage = *(cv::Mat *)tempAddrObj[i];
            trainImages.push_back(tempImage);
        }
        env->ReleaseLongArrayElements(tempAddrObj_, tempAddrObj, 0);
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", "already received from java");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow it down, try splitting `detectAndCompute()` into `detect()` and `compute()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints2;
cv::Mat descriptors2;

static void createKeypointsAndDescriptors(const cv::Mat& matInput) {
  //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector, compute the descriptors
    double minHessian = 400;
    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create();
    detector->setHessianThreshold(minHessian);

    detector->detect(matInput, keypoints2);
    detector->compute(matInput, keypoints2, descriptors2);
    // detector->detectAndCompute( matInput, noArray(), keypoints2, descriptors2 );        
...
}
```

### links:

[`cv::xfeatures2d::SURF Class Reference`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/df7/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1SURF.html)
[`cv::Feature2D Class Reference`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html#a8be0d1c20b08eb867184b8d74c15a677)
[`cv::xfeatures2d::AffineFeature2D Class Reference`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/db2/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1AffineFeature2D.html#a96d437af348dc676a3860d755555a249)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was solved. matInput is not empty, but keypoints2 and descriptors are empty. Do you know why it is..??

Comment: @MJ Kwon `keypoints2` and `descriptors2` are empty because they were not detected (see updated code). What image are you using ?

Comment: Are you talking about std::vector<Mat> trainImages? These are normal jpeg images. Please see edited part.